# Hibernate @Where clause based on One To many relative

Tags: java, hibernate

I have Parent class:

```
@Entity
public Class Parent
{
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent")
    public List<Child> children;
}
```

and Child class:

```
@Entity
public Class Child
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent")
    public Parent parent;

    @Column(name="isActive")
    public boolean isActive;
}
```

now I want to use @Where clause to let hibernate loads only Parents with all children inactive.

How can I do this using @Where or any other method?

Update:

the result I want to retrieve is like this SQL query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Parent p LEFT JOIN Child c ON c.parentid = p.id
WHERE c.isActive = 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do:

```
    @Entity
    public Class Parent
    {
        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent")
        @Where(clause = "isActive = false")
        public List<Child> children;
    }
```

---

Updated answer after new info:

So the way to want to do it, is impossible(at least from my knowledge).
The only way I know is to use a custom query, something like this:

```
    String query = "SELECT p FROM Parent p LEFT JOIN p.children Child WHERE children.isActive = 0";
    Query newquery = em.createQuery(query, Parent.class);
    List<Parent> parents = newquery.getResultList();
```

em is a EntityManager.

!! I am not sure about the p.children. If it does not work, please try with p.child

Comment: This is not what i need since i am updating a legacy code where i can't perform this query everywhere but thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following annotation to get your goal:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
public List<Child> children;
```

OR

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
public List<Child> children;
```

But be careful with second example, you can got an issue if you will trying to get some metadata from childer list: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1491

The bug still exist in hibernate 5.0.1-final.

However if you will use `LazyCollectionOption.TRUE` and will try to get childen size, you will get all children's data